# Где располагать upoload директорию для проекта на react+nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, файловая-система

Есть проект на react+redux и nodejs. Бандл собирается с помощью вебпака.
Структура проекта

`/dist` - бандл вебпака

`/src`

`-- /client` - здесь react+redux

`-- /server` - здесь весь бэкэнд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я осуществляю загрузку файлов для автара в форме регистрации.

Вопрос.

1) Где нужно хранить файлы которые я загружаю? В express уже задано - `app.use(express.static('dist'));`. Либо я использую неправильную структуру проекта. Тогда подскажите, как предпочтительно.

2) При загрузке я сохраняю файл и возвращаю строку на клиент вида `/uploads/avatar/***.png` и хочу тут же в компоненте отобразить это изображеие. Как лучше всего его выводить (при условии что есть дев сервер на 1234 порту и подакш на 3000). Нужно ли создавать отдельный компонент в котором формировать url кртинки исходя из переменных окружения?

Comment: а в чём проблема возвращать путь до картинки такого вида //example.com/pathToUpload/**.png. Ещё как вариант имена сохранённых изображений складывать в БД а сами файлы в S3 - подобное хранилище, и возвращать на клиент ссылку на S3 хост, в дальнейшем можно будет накрутить CDN на эти картинки со всеми плюсами CDN...

Comment: @xFloooo  вопрос в том, в какой именно директории праильно хранить картинки? 
Про s3 понятно. Как вариант можно и base64 картинки хранить в БД. Но меня интересует именно структурная часть хранения.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, вы хотите хранить вновь загружаемые картинки в проекте и возить их через репозиторий?

Comment: @xFloooo я хочу хранить файлы на сервере. В принципе я уже решил проблему. Просто переделал немного структуру проекта и все вопросы отпали, но спасибо за обсуждение в любом случае). Есть другой вопрос. 
При регистрации я загружаю файлы на сервер и потом отображаю этот файл в компоненте. Есть так же кнопка, которая удаляет этот файл, если не тот загрузил/не понравилось. Нужно ли мне отправлять какой-то токен с фронта для удаления? Ведь в теории мы может отправить запрос и удалить аватар пользователя, зная имя картинки?

Comment: я бы вообще ничего на сохранял на сервере пока пользователь не нажмёт кнопку `сохранить` (картинку так же можно показывать, но не загружать на сервер), а когда у него уже будет свой аккаунт, то у него должны быть некие права на то что ему позволено.А там уже как реализуете будет это работать через json токен или через сессию

Comment: @xFloooo Можете подсказать, как можно отображать изображение, не загружая его?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93922/discussion-between-alexey-kapustsin-and-xfloooo).